# Trying to compare lines of 2 large files and keep lines that match, but no matches

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary file for a speech recognition engine that I'm trying to reduce the size of. The dictionary contains 133k+ lines like so:

```
abella AH B EH L AH
abeln AE B IH L N
abelow AE B AH L OW
abels EY B AH L Z
abelson AE B IH L S AH N
abend AE B EH N D
abend(2) AH B EH N D
```

I'm trying to reduce it to only hold the most common words and names in the U.S. from a file with 15k+ lines like so:

```
configurations
poison
james
john
robert
```

When I run the following script it results in a blank file, as if there no matches between the first token of lines in the dictionary and the lines of the common words dataset. Are my files too big for the way I'm doing this? What am I doing wrong?

```
import os

file_name = 'small_cmudict-en-us.dict'
f = open(file_name, 'w+')

with open('common_names_words.txt', 'r') as n:
        for line in n:
                line = line[:-1] #remove newline char
        with open('cmudict-en-us.dict', 'r') as d:
                for line2 in d:
                        dict_entry = line2.split()

                        #words with multiple pronunciations; abend, abend(2)
                        if dict_entry[0][-3:] == '(': 
                                if dict_entry[0][:-3] in n:
                                        f.write(line)

                        if dict_entry[0] in n:
                                f.write(line)
f.close
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Words with multiple pronunciations will have "(some_number)" attached to the end of them. I'm trying to keep all pronunciations of each match. That's why I tried to check for both scenarios (with a number on the end and not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. First, you iterate the entire file but don't save anything

```
for line in n:
        line = line[:-1] #remove newline char
```

Then you ask if the word you want is in the file that you've already exhausted with that loop

```
if dict_entry[0] in n:
```

As soon as you are in the business of checking containment, you should be thinking sets. They provide fast lookup of hashable objects like strings. You can also "normalize" the data by stripping off things like the `(2)` and deciding on a case to compare. Perhaps both files are already lower case, but I assumed the case can vary.

```
file_name = 'small_cmudict-en-us.dict'

with open(file_name, 'w+') as f:

    with open('common_names_words.txt', 'r') as n:
        common = set(line.strip().lower() for line in n)

    with open('cmudict-en-us.dict', 'r') as d:
        for line2 in d:
            # account for e.g, "abend" and "abend(2)"
            word = line2.split()[0].split('(')[0].strip().lower()
            if word in common:
                f.write(line2)
```

You could also compress that code a bit by using `writelines` and a generator that filters lines for you.

```
    with open('cmudict-en-us.dict', 'r') as d:
        f.writelines(line for line in d
            if line.split()[0].split('(')[0].strip().lower() in common)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm having some trouble with this line: common = set(line.strip().lower() for in line in n). I assume it's storing each line as an element in the set but I'm not sure. I get a syntax error and when I removed that first 'in' to resolve it I get a message that 'line' is not defined.

Comment: I got it to work using a list instead of a set (just because I'm more familiar with that) and tweaked a couple of things. Thanks again for your help and advice.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the bugs. I updated the answer. A `set` is similar to a list except that it only allows 1 entry of a given value (if the orginal file as "abend" multiple times you'll only get one copy) and the "in" operator is faster. If you've got 15K common words, it will have a significant benefit. That said, the list will work too.